# Find a value that satisfies if-else condition

Tags: r, if-statement

I have this dataframe:

```
dx <- structure(list(a = c(0.916290731874155, 2.89037175789616, 2.14658084451746, 
-2.62103882411258, -2.07944154167984, 2.00533356952611, -1.24319351747922, 
0.42744401482694, 1.29532258291416, -2.03292152604494, -0.606135803570316, 
-0.693147180559945), b = c(0.550046336919272, 0.228258651980981, 
-0.577634293438101, 0.135801541159061, 0.644357016390513, -2.30258509299405, 
-0.0870113769896297, 1.71297859137494, 0.17958557697508, -1.65140211153313, 
1.31218638896617, 2.19935904986485), c = c(0.0988458346366325, 
-3.34403896782221, 1.99243016469021, 0.737598943130779, 0.178691788743376, 
2.20727491318972, -1.40242374304977, -1.256836293883, -2.16905370036952, 
2.91777073208428, 0.138586163286146, -0.946143695023836), d = c(2.57963390914446, 
-5.14458326660599, 1.83258146374831, 1.15057202759882, 0.0613689463762919, 
-2.23359222150709, 4.34236137828145, -3.44854350225935, 1.29098418131557, 
-0.356674943938732, -0.21868920096483, -0.810930216216329), e = c(1.65140211153313, 
0.220400065368459, -0.044951387862266, 0.0773866636154201, -1.49877234454658, 
1.36219680954083, 2.07179039494432, -3.07731226054641, -0.916290731874155, 
1.65822807660353, 0.451985123743057, -0.810930216216329)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 2:13)
```

I created a variable "sd" to have the average of each column and the variable "sqmat" which gives me the square root of each value of the dataframe. I put these two variables in relation to know if the single value of dx divided by 3 was greater than the average of the respective column multiplied by 4. If so, it gives me 1, otherwise it gives me 0. So I get a matrix for the which I want to know when the first 1 appears in each column.

```
sd <- (colSums(dx)/12)
sqmat <- sqrt(abs(dx))
G <- ifelse((sqmat/3) > (sd*4), 1, 0)
open <- t(as.matrix(max.col(t(G) == 1, "first")))
```

then I considered only column 1 and column 3 to understand which of the two dx values in correspondence with the row that I found in "open" for the respective two columns was greater

```
if (dx[open[,1],1] > dx[open[,3],3]) {
      s <- dx[open[,1],1]
      b <- dx[open[,3],3]
    } else{
      s <- dx[open[,3],3]
      b <- dx[open[,1],1]
    }
```

now I need to know the number of the row, following the one considered in the previous condition, where this condition is reversed. in other words, the row in which the column that had the greater value than the other, is the smaller after.

In this case I expect that the first row after s and b, which the value of the col 1 is less than the value of the col 3 is the 4th.

How can I do? I hope I was clear. Thx everyone!

Comment: The best way to ask a question is to give data(the way you have done) and then explain what you want and then give the output of what you want, The code should be written under `my attempts`

Comment: just what you have attempted. If you want to can completely ignore the code. Just include the data that you finaly want

Comment: I think my question mirrors your suggestions, right?

Comment: Your question explains the code rather than explaining what you need. Do not use the code to explain what you want. Just explain what you want without refering to the script

Comment: I think I don't know how to explain it better than how i did

Comment: how were you able to write the code? there is some reasoning behind the code. that is what you need to explain. Assume there was no code, how would you explain what you want to be done? The reason probably why no one has answered this question is because of that. note that people think differently to solve the same task. so if you explain your code, you are forcing somene to think like you. instead of explaining the code, explain the logic that made you write the code

Comment: I tried again, what do you think about?